Converting a dynamic string array to an object with keys
I have the following string array:
let arrayExample = ['', 'test1', 'test2', '', 'test3', 'test1', ''];

This is also dynamic, so the size can change at any given time. I would like to be able to convert this to an object that looks like the following:
{
    Property0: '',
    Property1: 'test1',
    Property2: 'test2',
    Property3: '',
    Property4: 'test3',
    Property5: 'test1',
    Property6: ''
}

Is there a way to dynamically declare the keys/property names? I've tried the following, but this seems to assign keys as numerical values and I'm not able to access them:
newArrayExample = Object.assign({}, arrayExample);
console.log(newArrayExample);
// { 0: '', 1: 'test1', 2: 'test2', 3: '', 4: 'test3', 5: 'test1', 6: '' }

I've also tried using reduce(), but that seems to only bring back unique values and I need to preserve those values unless if I'm using it wrong:
newArrayExample = arrayExample.reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: v}), {});


The best way is by using reduce() method, but you are using it wrong.
Since the property name is set to the value of the array element itself [v] you'll encounter two main issues:
1. Duplicate Values: If the array contains duplicate values (like test1 appears twice in your example), using the value as a key will overwrite the previous property with the same key. Therefore, you will lose some data in the final object.
2. Empty Strings as Keys: If the array contains empty strings (like in your example), the property key will be an empty string, which is generally not desirable.


let arrayExample = ['', 'test1', 'test2', '', 'test3', 'test1', ''];

let result = arrayExample.reduce((acc, value, index) => {
  acc[`Property${index}`] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);




I'm running into the following error with the assignment line: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type \Property${number}` can't be used to index type '{}'.`

because you are using typescript, hence you need to define the types of parameters, replace (acc, value, index) with this (acc: {[key: string]: string}, value: string, index: number)
